# making sulfuric acid from pyrite

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics

I recently found a place with an insane amount of pyrite (we are talking about tons) already smashed into smaller pieces, and I'm wondering if there is any way of converting it into sulfuric acid.

I'm aware that this is possible:

$$\ce{4 FeS2 + 11 O2 -> 2 Fe2O3 + 8 SO2}$$
$$\ce{2 SO2 + 2 H2O + O2 -> 2 H2SO4}$$

but it requires to heat up pyrite to quite some temperature :/

Is there any chemical extraction method available?

Comment: What's wrong with heating? Yes, chemical methods without heating are technically possible, but insanely costly.

Comment: I was an apprentice in a fertilizer manufacturing industry and sulphuric acid was produced on site from originally iron pyrites and then more cheaply from pure sulphur. So look at the costs before venturing forth. I don't know the exact details but nitric acid was also used to 'get the sulphuric acid production going' after releasing the SO2 from the pyrites.
Spent iron was shipped to blast furnace for steel production. But we are talking thousands of tons over a year. There was no water with pure sulphur...

Comment: SO2 will not give you sulphuric acid. In a technical process, vanadium pentoxide is used to oxidize it to SO3. Please always take proper safety measures handling acids and gases for you and your environment.

Comment: The production of sulfuric acid will be cumbersome. May I suggest that you try to broker the material to an industry that has the equipment to use it. It could be a WIN-WIN for all involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a direct reaction to convert pyrite to sulfuric acid by treating it with nitric acid.

$$\ce{FeS2 + 18HNO3 → Fe(NO3)3 + 2H2SO4 + 15NO2 + 7H2O}$$

> Iron(II) disulfide react with and nitric acid to produce iron(III)
>   nitrate, sulfuric acid, nitrogen dioxide and water. Nitric acid -
>   concentrated solution. The reaction takes place in a boiling solution.([source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-5450))

But the problem is that iron(III) nitrate is soluble and does not precipitate in the solution. You have to distill off the sulfuric acid.

So, in my opinion heating pyrite in oxygen and then hydro-oxidising sulfur dioxide produced to form sulfuric acid is the cheap and efficient way because it does not require any additional chemicals as @Ivan mentioned.

Also, if you have money/curiosity, try using a cheap, oxidizing agent like [nitrous](http://chemiday.com/reaction/3-1-0-8067) or [nitric oxide](http://chemiday.com/reaction/3-1-0-8034). The advantage in this process is that the products beside sulfuric acid are gases which can leave easily but I recommend you to stick to the plan.